# Can not create objects of Identity classes (UserManager and RoleManager)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, data-access-layer

I am developing a 3 tier architecture app, so I add UserManager and RoleManager to my UnitOfWork at Data Access Layer. 
But when I try to create objects of UserManager and RoleManager classes I get this errors:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'optionsAccessor' 
of 'UserManager<IdentityUser>.UserManager(IUserStore<IdentityUser>, IOptions<IdentityOptions>, 
IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<IdentityUser>>, 
IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, 
IServiceProvider, ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>>)'

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'roleValidators'
 of 'RoleManager<IdentityRole>.RoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<IdentityRole>>, 
ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, ILogger<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>)'
```

Part of my UnitOfWork class

```
    public class IdentityUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private ApplicationContext _context;

        public IdentityUnitOfWork(ApplicationContext context)
        {
            _userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(context);// error 1
            _roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(context);// error 2
            _context = context;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE

When I try to create my own `RoleManager` and `UserManager` classes, I get the same error.

My `ApplicationRole` class

```
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {

    }
```

My `ApplicationRoleManager` class

```
    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(RoleStore<ApplicationRole> store)
                    : base(store)// error in a here (in a base)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can simply inject your constructor with the classes. Make sure to register `IUnitOfWork` as a service, and `IdentityUnitOfWork` as the implementation.

Comment: `IUnitOfWork` and `IdentityUnitOfWork` are already registered in my `Startup.cs` on API layer, butt this does not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added identity service to IoC container. So you can use dependency injection into UnitOfWork's constructor like this:

```
public class IdentityUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private ApplicationContext _context;

    public IdentityUnitOfWork(ApplicationContext context, 
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solve my problem, but I am not sure that it is correct to pass UserManager and RoleManager in constuctor.

Comment: It seems you are not familiar with dependency injection. When you add identity as a service to your application, an instance of UserManager and RoleManager are available in IoC container. Therefore you can inject them into uow. It's not passing parameters, It's dependency injection. How do you initialize uow??

Comment: On Business Logic Layer I cant get instances of `UserManager` and `RoleManager` because they are not initialized in uow

Comment: After application startup, you can get instances everywhere in your code. I guess you are trying to get instancec using ```new``` keyword.

Comment: When I try to get `UserManager` or `RoleManager` I get this error:

`'IUnitOfWork' does not contain a definition for 'RoleManager' and no accessible extension method 'RoleManager' accepting a first argument of type 'IUnitOfWork' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I can get every other property from my `UnitOfWork` because they are initialized in a `get` method, if I remove initialization, I cant get them like `UserManager` and `RoleManager`

Comment: I had edit my post 6 hours ago, If the problem there will be fixed, I will figure out how to fix any other.